# How to use style explicitly from implicit theme?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I want to use `ToggleButton` styles from a theme available freely from: [brianlagunas.com](http://brianlagunas.com/free-metro-light-and-dark-themes-for-wpf-and-silverlight-microsoft-controls/).

Problem is, if I apply the theme, not only my toggle button is styled, but every control is styled according to that theme.

How do I apply style explicitly from a theme designed to be used implicitly?

How the theme is loaded

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Light Theme -->
            <ResourceDictionary
             Source="Themes/Metro/Light/Metro.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary
             Source="Themes/Metro/Light/Metro.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml" />
            <!-- Dark Theme -->
            <!--
                <ResourceDictionary
                 Source="Themes/Metro/Dark/MetroDark.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary
                 Source="Themes/Metro/Dark/MetroDark.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml" />
            -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Light Theme -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundKey" Color="#FFFFFF" />
        <!-- Dark Theme -->
        <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundKey" Color="#FF181818" />-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

How can I plan to use the theme:

```
<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Width="150"
    Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you gonna need to set a `x:Key` to every theme. With that, you can use it as you planned.

Comment: @Tico Okay, but how do i do that? I cant use resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries cant I? What should I use? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you should put each `x:Key` at the files such: `Metro.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you load a `ResourceDictionary` that defines implicit style for `ToggleButton`.

Since the download page you linked is actually downloading a full solution, you have these options:

1. Go to `Metro.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml` and copy the style of toggle button to your resources (the one with `ToggleButtonStyle` key, and don't forget to "bring" along all necessary brushes).
2. Since there are no DLLs there, I'll assume you compiled the project/solution - so you can recompile it. If so, go to the same file and comment out this line:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"
    TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" />
```

(one before last style in the file)

Recompile it and you're good to go.

I'd definitely choose option No. 2.